# Genesis Onyx 29" New tires? New wheels?

Tags: tire

I want replacement tires for this bike.  I believe they are 29" x 2.125.   Can I buy tires that are more narrow for the same rim/wheel?  2" 1.75?   Also,  Is it possible/practical to swap the wheels for 26" wheels?  One last question,  since I'm new to this,  is 29" tires the same as 700cc?

thanks

Comment: 2.125 to 1.75 is probably doable, but it all really depends on your rims and how "fat" they are.  Changing to 26" is impractical.  29" is a marketing term for 700c, to make it sound more 'Merican.

Comment: thanks for all the help. The brakes are coaster brakes for this bike. does that matter when dealing with wheel size? The only reason I was looking at the possiblity of changing the wheel size is that there seems to be a lot more to choose from in the 26 inch world than the 29 inch. Its not that big of a deal. I was just wondering. thanks

Comment: Since 29" and 700c are the same thing, you have a vast selection of tires in that size.

Answer (score 2):

In general, switching to a slightly less wide tire should not cause any problems, unless the tires are much too narrow for the rims. Sheldon Brown's [Tire Sizing page](http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html) (under Width Considerations), suggests that if the tires are much too narrow, this can cause pinch flats and rim damage. If you're just going down a few sizes, you should be fine.

Switching to 26" wheels is impractical. The brakes wouldn't line up with the rims, and I don't know how you could fix this. Maybe someone else will have a suggestion, but my hunch is that if it's even possible at all, switching to smaller wheels could easily cost more than the bike is worth, especially for a bike in this price range (about $150?). Do you have any particular reason that you would want smaller diameter wheels?

Finally, 29" tires are the same diameter as 700c (also mentioned on the [Tire Sizing page](http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html)). However, make sure not to use tires that are really narrow relative to the rims.